# Can you suggest any android authenticating way except facebook API?

Tags: android, facebook

I was developing app which uses Facebook API authentication for user login.

But sometimes login process was seriously slow(it took 4~5mins for finishing authenticating 
facebook user). So I am thinking alternative athentication ways except facebook APIs.

Can you suggest any alternative authentications?

Twitter has open API which uses oAuth(same as Facebook).

Are there any other site implements oAuth and have an open API so I can refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the long auth time is not because of some bug in your code?

Long authentication time in all probability is not a problem on Facebook's side (there recently was some downtime though; have you tried in the last couple of hours?): millions of customers rely on their auth system. I'd think that the auth time would be comparable on any other service as well.

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java is a well known auth library which provides for authentication via many OpenId providers like Yahoo!, Google and Facebook. You will possibly get better auth response times from a standard library like this.

Comment: I dont know, I use Facebook graph API so there might be rare chance to getting code error. I uses Facebook SingleSignOn method and this method uses offical facebook app package and classes. There is nothing much I can do. I dont know why but looks like this is only me who have long auth time problem. anyways, thanks for suggesting scribe-java. I will try to look the source.